# Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: doc is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: doc is not defined

Source
components\Modal.js (42:18) @ updateDoc

  40 | await uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, "data_url").then(async (snapshot) => {
  41 |     const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
> 42 |     await updateDoc(doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id), {
     |          ^
  43 |         image: downloadURL
  44 |     })
  45 | });
Call Stack
async uploadPost
```

I cannot find the error in it but after uploading the image this erroe pop up and but my image gets uploaded in firbase storage bucket

Answer (score 1):

You've most probably forgot to import the `doc()` function:

```
import { doc, updateDoc, ... } from "firebase/firestore";
```

Comment: Hello @Ved-code, did you have the time to look at the answer?